# MySQL Query in a View

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I have the following query I use and it works great:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(
SELECT * FROM `Transactions` ORDER BY DATE DESC
) AS tmpTable

GROUP BY Machine
ORDER BY Machine ASC
```

What's not great, is when I try to create a view from it. It says that subqueries cannot be used in a view, which is fine - I've searched here and on Google and most people say to break this down into multiple views. Ok.

I created a view that orders by date, and then a view that just uses that view to group by and order by machines - the results however, are not the same. It seems to have taken the date ordering and thrown it out the window.

Any and all help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the solution, after hours of trying, apparently you can use a subquery on a WHERE but not FROM?

```
CREATE VIEW something AS

SELECT * FROM Transactions AS t
WHERE Date =
(
  SELECT MAX(Date)
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE Machine = t.Machine
)
```

Comment: Dude, you should work on your way of clarifying what you want to achieve. I could have told you 40 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery here. You want to have the latest date in the group of machines, right?

So just do

```
SELECT
t.*, MAX(date)
FROM Transactions t
GROUP BY Machine
ORDER BY Machine ASC /*this line is obsolete by the way, since in MySQL a group by automatically does sort, when you don't specify another sort column or direction*/
```

A GROUP BY is used together with a aggregate function (in your case MAX()) anyway.

Alternatively you can also specify multiple columns in the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
Transactions
GROUP BY Machine
ORDER BY Date DESC, Machine ASC
```

should give you also what you want to achieve. But using the MAX() function is definitely the better way to go here.

Actually I have never used a GROUP BY without an aggregate function.

Comment: I have other fields in the table, and your first example it gives me all of the information as if it were an old entry but adds a new column that does show the correct latest date. The second one does not always show the latest date, as far as I know MySQL groups by the Machine first and then sorts all of the machines by date. So what I really need here is all of the transactional information for the most recent transaction on each machine.

Comment: Well, I didn't try the second approach, but it's no surprise to me, that there are incorrect results. The first approach is definitely the right way to go. The * or t.* gives you all the columns in your table and I added the Max(date) column, yes. Usually one would write out all column names, so you don't run into trouble when your table changes. When you do that, just replace your date column with MAX(date) and you will have no extra column. But what do you mean with "as if it were an old entry"?